# TSQL Select random rows WITH running total

Tags: t-sql, random, sql-server-2012, cumulative-sum

TSQL, I am using SQL 2012 but will use anything that works from previous versions. I know how to select TOP X random rows from a table using NEWID().   Separately, I know how to select a running total using several methods, CTE, etc.

BUT, how would one combine these 2 results into one query?  So I want to select say 3 random records (AND no less than 3), where the running total does not exceed 15.  Can't wrap my head around this one...

Use this simple table and data:

```
CREATE TABLE TblTest (
   id    int not null identity(1,1) primary key,
   value int not null
);

INSERT INTO TblTest (value) VALUES (4);
INSERT INTO TblTest (value) VALUES (3);
INSERT INTO TblTest (value) VALUES (5);
INSERT INTO TblTest (value) VALUES (6);
INSERT INTO TblTest (value) VALUES (6);
INSERT INTO TblTest (value) VALUES (5);
INSERT INTO TblTest (value) VALUES (6);
INSERT INTO TblTest (value) VALUES (5);
INSERT INTO TblTest (value) VALUES (4);
INSERT INTO TblTest (value) VALUES (7);
INSERT INTO TblTest (value) VALUES (7);
INSERT INTO TblTest (value) VALUES (6);
INSERT INTO TblTest (value) VALUES (5);
INSERT INTO TblTest (value) VALUES (4);
```

My Attempt is below, not sure if it even makes sense having the NEWID there, and sometimes it returns only 2 rows, sometimes 0, I want it to be smart enough to return always 3 rows, and if possible, closest to 15...:

```
select top(3) ourRandID,
       id, 
       value, 
       running_total
from (
    select NEWID() as ourRandID, 
            id,
           value,
           sum(value) over (order by NEWID()) as running_total
    from TblTest
) t
where running_total < 16
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this:

```
 select     t.*
 from TblTest t
 join
 (
 select top (1) 
     t1.id [id1],t2.id [id2],t3.id [id3],
     t1.value[v1],t2.value [v2],t3.value [v3],
     t1.value+t2.value+t3.value [sum]
 from TblTest t1
 join TblTest t2 on (t1.id <> t2.id)
 join TblTest t3 on (t3.id <> t2.id and t3.id <> t1.id)
 where t1.value+t2.value+t3.value <= 15
 order by t1.value+t2.value+t3.value desc,newid() 
 ) [a] on (t.id=a.id1 or t.id=a.id2 or t.id=a.id3)
```

Comment: Very nice. I should have thought about getting back to the basics like this. So far this has yet to fail / go over 15 and always returns 3 records, and always seems to total to 15 which is good. This will most likely be my answer. Thanks Stanley!

Comment: However this one is a lot slower, once testing on my live data which is completely different. was hoping to use the newer SQL 2012 functionality  
-ALso it is difficult to change it to return the TOP 5 records (or any number), without re-writing the bulk of it, adding v4, v5, etc. And when I did add more tables, t3, t4, it gets exponentially slower. Darn I need different versions to return up to 10... hmmm

Comment: i see how this can get very slow if you add more joins...maybe try to pre-generate the joins into a new table with a clustered index on sum(t1.value+t2.value ...)